# NG Zorro Multi Select - keep selected items on one line instead of wrapping and doubling height

Tags: css, ng-zorro-antd

Anyone know if there is a way to make the ng zorro select (multi) to stick to one line instead of wrapping the selected items. In some scenarios its fine but when you have certain layouts you cant have the height doubling on each selection.

There is a codebox demo here: https://codesandbox.io/s/2lp2n (reduce the size of the view panel to see what i mean).

I have tried pretty much all i can think of (adding css to the select and select top classes to try and force it to stay on one line but it doesnt seem to work). I wanted to ask here first to see if anyone has any ideas since their git would normally close a question and ask me to come here first.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In the end i just had to add:

```
flex-wrap: nowrap !important;
```

to nz-select-top-control